# Поиск информации, прочитанной из файла, в других файлах

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

У меня есть 2 файла (пусть будут tmp1.txt и tmp2.txt). В tmp1.txt есть слово qwe, а в tmp2.txt есть строка "fsdg fgh q fh qwe fgh sd". Как найти с помощью grep это слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось, тут всё просто

```
cat tmp1.txt | grep -f - tmp2.txt
```

Comment: `cat` Не нужен.

Comment: А как тогда можно было сделать? То есть чтобы шаблон с tmp1.txt оказался в grep